# Why is a Riemannian metric $g$?

Tags: notation, riemannian-geometry

A Riemannian metric on a manifold is universally denoted with the letter $g$, but unlike many other mathematical objects like a function $f$, a distance $d$, a manifold $M$ or a group $G$ there does not seem to be a connection to the name or meaning of the actual quantity, neither in English nor German.

**Questions:**

- When and where has this notation been introduced?
- Is there an evident reason why the letter $g$ was chosen and accepted by everyone?

---

**Some Remarks:**

- Of course $g$ carries a lot of information about the **g**eometry of a manifold, but this seems to be a little too unspecific to me.
- In his book on Riemannian geometry, Do Carmo only uses $g_{ij}$ but never $g$ for the metric. On the other hand at some point he uses $g$ for the **G**auss-map of a surface, but that also does not directly relate to the metric tensor.
- Do Carmo also points out that Riemann introduced the concept of a quadratic form assigned to each point of a manifold in his paper "[*Über die Hypothesen, welche der Geometrie zugrunde liegen*](https://www.emis.de/classics/Riemann/Geom.pdf)." But in there I did not find the notation $g$ as well.

Comment: Is this notation due to Riemann? Or could it be due to Einstein, for gravity?

Comment: The use of $g$ goes at least as far back as Einstein. It's used in his [1915 paper](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/129).

Comment: @Winther: That is interesting. The symbol $g$ being used by Einstein might at least explain its universal acceptance nowadays.

Comment: Maybe because the notion of the metric tensor comes from the works of **G**auss on invariant properties of a surface?

Comment: there are several people to look at in the late 1800's to early 1900's, an early one who used the tensor as such was Beltrami, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugenio_Beltrami The same article mentions his influence on Ricci and on his student Levi-Civita  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorio_Ricci-Curbastro

Comment: also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elwin_Bruno_Christoffel

Comment: Why do we use the letter * for denoting ** has, in most cases, nothing to do with the history of mathematics. .

Comment: Maybe you want to move your question to hsm.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4):

The letter "g" was originally used by Albert Einstein for *gravity*.

See [this answer](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/3436) and references therein.

Answer (score 2):

I always thought it was $g$ for the [**G**ram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix), which, after picking a basis, specifies the component of an inner product:

$g_{ij} = \langle \hat{e}_i, \hat{e}_j \rangle$

On a Riemannian manifold, the metric is just an inner product-valued field.

Answer (score -1):

The symbol $\mathbb Z$ is used because the German word for number is Zahlen.

In German, "gestalt" means "shape", "form", "figure", etc.

Perhaps this is the reason behind the choice of $g$.

Comment: Writing "Zahlen", and not "zahlen", one should also write "Gestalt", and not "gestalt", ...

Comment: But *Gestalt* is a vague as *Geometrie*, surely connected to the big picture, but not so much to the concept of a bilinear form at every point.